# Convert 17-jun-87 to '17-jun-1987 21:55:45'

Tags: sql, oracle

table x

Hire_date

17-jun-87

how to convert it to  '17-jun-1987 21:55:45' ?

I tried couple ways using to_char function or to_date function but getting some error

select to_char(hire_Date, 'dd-mmm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') but was not successful ?

any suggestions please?

Comment: Where the time part comes from?

Comment: usually in that way, if there is not time mentioned defaultly it takes as 00:00:00

Comment: Have you tried `select to_char(hire_Date, 'dd-MON-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')`?

Comment: i have added the comment as answer. feel free to upvote/aceept it if it has helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
select to_char(hire_Date, 'dd-MON-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have mmm instead of mon

```
select to_char(hire_Date, 'dd-mmm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

change it to

select to_char(hire_Date, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')

should work